# Unable to reference a named range in VBA - method range of object _global failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have two macros, they are identical with the exception of a the named ranged differences.  Some named ranges which I've either manually defined or defined via VBA.  The first macro (CleanProcesses) works fine but the second brings me up with an error, either an 'Application-Defined or Object-Defined error' or a 'method range of object _global failed' messge when tweaking the code to "**Set rng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ReportingDetail")"**.  Here's the code:

```
Sub CleanProcesses()
Dim Processrng As Range
Set Processrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("Process").RefersToRange
If Range("ProcessesRowNum").Value <= 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

Dim I

Range(Processrng, Range(Processrng).End(xlDown)).Name = "ProcessesRange"
ProcessesRangeIRow = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ProcessesRange").Count - 2

For I = 1 To ProcessesRangeIRow
Range(Processrng).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
targetrow = ActiveCell.Row
Range(targetrow & ":" & targetrow).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A" & targetrow - 1).Select
Next I
End Sub


Sub CleanReporting()
Dim Reportingrng As Range
####**Set Reportingrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("ReportingDetail").RefersToRange
'Set Reportingrng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ReportingDetail")**####

If Range("ReportingRowNum").Value <= 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

Dim I
Range(Reportingrng, Range(Reportingrng).End(xlDown)).Name = "ReportingRange"
ReportingRangeIRow = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ReportingRange").Count - 2

For I = 1 To ReportingRangeIRow
Range(Reportingrng).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
targetrow = ActiveCell.Row
Range(targetrow & ":" & targetrow).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A" & targetrow - 1).Select
Next I
End Sub
```

I've put hashes ### on the line of code I'm getting the error on.  I can't seem to figure out how I can get past this?  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you press F5 in Excel and select the "ReportingDetail" name it gets you where it should? It works fine?

Comment: Are you sure the named range exists?

Comment: Try to use Set Reportingrng = Sheets("Sheetname").Range("ReportingDetail").RefersToRange instead of Set Reportingrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("ReportingDetail").RefersToRange

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I can confirm the named range is present when I F5.  Unfortunately, the named range is ReportDetail not ReportingDetail (my bad - I've been tweaking it alot).  I've changed it to:

    Set Reportingrng = Worksheets("Overview").Range("ReportDetail")

However, I now get the _Global Failed error on this line:

        Range(Reportingrng, Range(Reportingrng).End(xlDown)).Name = "ReportingRange"

Comment: @zaptask - so I've tweaked the code to this but I get an error (Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed) on the blow line of code.  I can confirm the named ranges do exist and their names are correct in the code now.

Range(Reportingrng, Range(Reportingrng).End(xlDown)).Name = "ReportingRange"

Comment: @japandave I can confirm the named range exists albeit I had put the wrong name in my code originally (sorry)

Comment: Use Reportingrng.End(xlDown) instead of Range(Reportingrng).End(xlDown)

Comment: @zaptask - It worked - thank you so much.